# What kind of virus is Thrax from Osmosis Jones?

Tags: movie, animation, osmosis-jones

I have three theories:

1. Thrax is the rabies virus (because he attacks the brain) (also, he hates being compared to the ebolavirus, and ebolaviruses and the rabies virus both belong to the *Mononegavirales* order);
2. Thrax is a cytomegalovirus that has become lethal (because cytomegaloviruses are DNA viruses, and they exceptionally attack the brain) (Thrax wanted to steal Frank's DNA genome);
3. Thrax is a human immunodeficiency virus (because Frank touched a chimpanzee before he caught Thrax).

Comment: Going by his name, I think anthrax would be most likely.

Comment: He seems to be a conglomeration of tropes. His name is "Thrax" (presumably from [An]thrax, he's described as "The Red Death" and he whistles "Fever" all the time.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Anthrax is bacterial

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thrax was originally conceived as ["a common cold"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold), then re-written as the "[*Hong-Kong flu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_flu)" when the makers thought that they might get Jet-Li attached to the film. Over time he became less specific and more tropey, ending up as **Scarlet Fever**....

> "*La Muerte Roja!*" [The Red Death]

.... but with inconsistencies that likely exist because of how the script was persistently re-written. You might also want to note that he's literally scarlet and persistently hums the tune "*[Fever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=19&v=UFpshq8fCGI&feature=youtu.be)*".

> **Q:** *That's what I was going to ask.  When you pitched this, what has really changed since then?*
>
> **Marc:** *Well, a few things changed.  In the very original...very little has changed from the actual pitch.  I have the pitch cards I used when I pitched the story.  I did conceive it originally that the whole thing would just be about...have you seen the movie yet?*
>
> **Q:** Yes.
>
> **Marc:** ***Would just be about a common cold.**  At the end of the movie, in the pitch, his wife said - Frank had a wife, not a daughter at the time - said, "Honey, are you feeling okay?" He said, "I thought I was getting sick there for a minute, but I guess I'm going to be okay," like the whole movie was that.*
>
> **Zak:** *It was a counterpoint between how little he cared in real life versus how much we cared in the movie.*
>
> **Marc:** *Yeah, and it wasn't a change...it was a change that I think we wanted to make to make the stakes greater and make it a life or death illness.  That's one change.  **Thrax was originally conceived as the Hong Kong flu who was a bad ass Asian virus - sort of a Jet Li character.  Other than that...the live-action...***
>
> <sub><sup>[INTERVIEW WITH THE SCREENWRITER & PRODUCER](http://am.animatedviews.com/OsmosisJones.html)</sup></sub>